# Insert blank page using Print Dialog

Tags: windows, linux, mac, printing

Is there a way to insert a blank page anywhere in the document using the print dialog?

The use case in my mind:
While in print dialog, if it were possible to direct the printer to insert blank pages after certain pages using the "Pages" field, it will be a really convenient way for the user to dynamically (per print job) create separators. For example 1-6!7-10 would print pages 1 to 6 normally, then leave a page blank, and then print pages 7 to 10.

Well, you might say, after the printing is done, take some blank pages and insert them manually. But hey, my technique is really useful in case of double-sided printing.

My question is Linux targeted. But, why not, tell me about Windows/Mac too.

Comment: Yes, it would be great for manual double-sided printing! If there isn't currently a way, I hope that at least Linux implements such a feature.

Comment: insert pages: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oz2KmKKOQGU  (this shows how to do it automatically)